# Meijer G-function in Python and scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, complex-numbers

I'm in need of a Meijer G function in scipy. I read somewhere on the internet that due to its generality, the Meier G function is not supported as a special function in scipy, but everyone should write something up according to his personal use case.

My problem is that I have no experience whatsoever with complex integration. As LaTeX is forbidden here, here's what I'm trying to solve numerically:

[image]

*(the first line being the general case, the second line my case that I'm trying to compute), with p(a), k, k2 given*

As [wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function#Definition_of_the_Meijer_G-function), there are three ways to get `L`:

- L runs from −i∞ to +i∞ such that all poles of Γ(bj − s), j = 1, 2, ..., m, are on the right of the path, while all poles of Γ(1 − ak + s), k = 1, 2, ..., n, are on the left.
- L is a loop beginning and ending at +∞, encircling all poles of Γ(bj − s), j = 1, 2, ..., m, exactly once in the negative direction, but not encircling any pole of Γ(1 − ak + s), k = 1, 2, ..., n.
- L is a loop beginning and ending at −∞ and encircling all poles of Γ(1 − ak + s), k = 1, 2, ..., n, exactly once in the positive direction, but not encircling any pole of Γ(bj − s), j = 1, 2, ..., m.

How do I get `L` and solve the integral? The way I'm used to compute integrals over the reals is to

```
import numpy as np
myL = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
densityL = myL[1] - myL[0]
myIntegral = (F(myL)*densityL).sum()
```

I'm not too much after efficiency, I'd prefer a simple and slow working example that I can use to understand the methodology.

Comment: As a side note, you should also have a look at [`scipy.integrate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html#module-scipy.integrate) to integrate in real space, in particular with `quad`. A simple summation will produce wrong  results for functions with singularities etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For something as complicated, I really think you should avoid calculating the integral yourself, especially if you don't have experience with complex integration, and use a well tested existing implementation.

Meijer G-function is implemented in [mpmath](https://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/functions/hypergeometric.html#meijerg) and possibly in [Sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/integrals/g-functions.html).

Answer (score 4):

```
import sympy
print(sympy.functions.special.hyper.meijerg([[], [-1/(k-1)], [0, 0], []], -p/k2).evalf())
import mpmath
print(mpmath.meijerg([[], [-1/(k-1)], [0, 0], []], -p/k2))
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).